# Tab Completion of Options for Command Line Utility

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, command-line-interface

I am using `click` to create a command line utility out of my python module. Unfortunately `click` does not provide bash completion for the various possible choices, which I need very much, and only gives the possible choices when you pass a wrong choice.

**My Code:**

```
import json
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--conn_obj', help='Connection Object')
@click.option('--entity', help='The entity you want to interact with. Example : Network, VM, Firewall etc.', type=click.Choice(['network','vm','firewall','eip','gateway','image','interface','network','route','subnet','tags','vm']))
@click.option('--operation', help='The operation you want to perform. Example : Create, Delete, List', type=click.Choice(['choice1','choice2','choice3']))
def execute(conn_obj,entity,operation,**kwargs):
    my_service = conn_obj.service
    my_connection = conn_obj.connection
    path = my_service + "/" + entity + ".json"
    with open(path) as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        method = json_data[operation]
        result = getattr(my_connection,method)(**kwargs)
    return result

if __name__=='__main__':
    execute()
```

From what I understand I have two choices:

- Use a different module other than `click` for creating the command-line utility. Unfortunately I was unable to find any that support bash completion. Any suggestions will be most helpful.
- Use some workaround/hack to achieve some sort of auto completion of possible values.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: according to the [docs](http://click.pocoo.org/5/bashcomplete/) click does support bash completion

Comment: According to the documentation : _Generally, the Bash completion support will complete subcommands and parameters._ I need bash completion for possible values of the parameters.